# Is there anyway to print dim3 values - Grid dimensions, block dimensions in Cuda?

Tags: cuda

I am trying to print the number of threads that I've used(declared in my code), and the number of blocks I'm creating. They are of the type : dim3
(I am using C programming.)

My code somehow looks like below:

```
//Declared a NxN grid
*int N = 4; //Num of rows
int numThreads = 4;
dim3 dimBlock(numThreads);
dim3 dimGrid((N/dimBlock.x)+(!(N%dimBlock.x)?0:1));
```

Could you please help me with how to get this printed on the terminal.
Using printf, which specifier is to be used; like we use %d for int, %f for floats, etc.

Answer (score 5):

You can use this kind of code to display the grid dimensions in blocks, and blocks dimensions in threads, before launching your kernel :

```
dim3 gridDim;
dim3 blockDim;

// here you set gridDim and blockDim to some values

printf("Grid : {%d, %d, %d} blocks. Blocks : {%d, %d, %d} threads.\n",
gridDim.x, gridDim.y, gridDim.z, blockDim.x, blockDim.y, blockDim.z);

kernel<<<gridDim, blockDim>>>();
```

With some research you could easily find how to do this.
Also remember you have [a documentation that covers the dim3 vector type](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#dim3) :

> This type is an integer vector type based on uint3 that is used to specify dimensions. When defining a variable of type dim3, any component left unspecified is initialized to 1.

So, as it uses unsigned integers, you could also use %u instead of %d in your printf call.